# DateTime that comes from a GET request uses different format than the one that comes from POST

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

the DateTime that comes from POST is binded correctly (according to my computer's format)

but DateTime values that come from GET doesn't bind correctly, it is using a different format

```
my format is dd.MM.yyyy, in GET it uses MM.dd.yyyy instead

I don't have this problem if I use the en-US format  (which is MM/dd/yyyy)
```

anybody knows how to fix this?

is this a mvc bug ? (it doesn't consider Culture when binding get requests)

Comment: Have you tested the application from multiple browsers to see if the behavior is constant?

Comment: @Rob, no I didn't, but I will, thnx for suggestion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it seems it isn't a bug. You can get more details here: [MVC DateTime binding with incorrect date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528545/mvc-datetime-binding-with-incorrect-date-format)

I've been using the following ModelBinder to solve that problem.

```
public class CurrentCultureDateTimeBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private const string PARSE_ERROR = "\"{0}\" is not a valid date";
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (valueProviderResult == null) return null;

        var date = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).AttemptedValue;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
            return null;

        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName));

        try
        {
            return DateTime.Parse(date);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, String.Format(PARSE_ERROR, bindingContext.ModelName));
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Omu It works because DateTime.Parse(String) uses the current thread culture (making the binder Culture aware). In contrast, the default binder uses CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. You can see more details here: http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx