# ASP.NET MVC: Html.Action / Html.ActionLink and culture specific DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I've been fighting with culture specific DateTime in ASP.NET MVC for few days now, to no avail.
The scenario is as follows: I have a list which I want to filter against DateTime submitted by user. Users should handle dates in a localized form, in my case culture and cultureUI is set to "da-DK", so date format is "dd-mm-yy". So far I've managed to make the form submit date in the required format, but Action and ActionLink methods generate URLs that interpret dates in en-US ("mm/dd/yy").

Here's a sample project displaying the issue. The culture in Web.config is hardcoded to "da-DK":

```
<globalization culture="da-DK" uiCulture="da-DK" />
```

First the controller with two actions:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace DateTimeTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ViewResult Index(DateModel model)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        public ViewResult Dummy(DateTime? date)
        {
            return View(date);
        }
    }

    public class DateModel
    {
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Index is an action displaying a form, where user can enter date in "dd-mm-yy" format. Form is posted to the same GET method (as I mentioned it's suppose to be filtering functionality), which will display the received date. Here's the Index.cshtml view:

```
@model DateTimeTest.Controllers.DateModel

<div>
    @if (Model.Date != null)
    {
        <p>Received @Model.Date</p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Dummy", "Dummy", new {Model.Date})
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @Html.EditorForModel()
    }
</div>
```

To make this work, I had to use a custom model binder, processing the DateTime. A simplified version looks as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace DateTimeTest.Infrastructure
{
    public class DateTimeBinder: IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            string date = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).AttemptedValue;

            DateTime? result = DateTime.Parse(date);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

This binder has been registered in Global.asax.cs with

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), new DateTimeBinder());
```

Now, when in the form I enter date "30-12-2013" and submit, Index view displays message "Received 30-12-2013 00:00:00" which is correct in my meaning. However the link to Dummy action looks like this:

```
http://localhost:53143/Home/Dummy?Date=12%2F30%2F2013%2000%3A00%3A00
```

which means the query string for Date is actually "12/30/2013 00:00:00". Clicking the link gives a FormatException in BindModel of the DateTimeBinder, because there are no 30 months in the calendar (it tries to process the date in da-DK format while what it gets is date in en-US). I know how to deal with exception itself but what I don't know is how to either force the system to use uniform DateTime format, or detect in the binder which format it comes in and act accordingly. I guess it boils down to question how URLs are generated by Html.Action and Html.ActionLink methods, though I might be wrong.

Note that I understand the need to treat GET URLs in en-US format (the post about fly tickets circulating around the web), though I would be willing to ignore this as the website I'm working on is an Intranet site where dates will only be used in da-DK format. Can anyone help me fix the issue? Thanks in advance.

PS. I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: @LostInComputer when I do that, I cannot submit the form. The validation message says "The value '30-12-2013' is not valid for Date."

Comment: "Note that I understand the need to treat GET URLs in en-US format (the post about fly tickets circulating around the web)" - Why is there a need to treat GET URLs in en-us format? I have no idea about this post you are talking about...

Comment: @Chris check the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528545/mvc-datetime-binding-with-incorrect-date-format?rq=1

Comment: Keep the globalization element but remove your custom binder. POST requests will follow the da-DK culture. I already verified this.

Comment: @LostInComputer I have commented the line adding custom binder in Global.asax.cs and as I said, it doesn't let me submit the form. I'm using English environment, so this might be the cause. However I'd like the form to allow submitting DateTime specifically in da-DK format, which contains dashes instead of slashes, which apparently are rejected by the validation mechanism...

Comment: Ah. More about invariant culture than en-US specifically. I'd never noticed that invariant culture did US style dates. I assumed it would use iso standard yyyy-mm-dd which, you know, is a universally recognised date format...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that having dug deep into the code for `ActionLink` (and following lots of method calls through lots of classes) it has this line:

```
builder2.Append(UrlEncode(Convert.ToString(obj3, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
```

Now the code is very complicated so I can't be 100% sure that this is the line that is causing you problems but I'd be relatively confident that if not there is another similar line elsewhere.

So the reason for your problem is that your ActionLink is generating in a Invariant culture context rather than the one you want. This is not going to be fixable.

You could probably fix it by just using a ToString and specifying your culture (or presumably allowing it to use the default).

N.B. The line of code quoted above was found via Reflector in `System.Web.Routing.ParsedRoute.Bind(...)`. `ParsedRoute` is an internal class. Its in the System.Web.dll assembly.

Comment: Thanks Chris, where do you suggest I use the ToString method?

Comment: I was thinking just in your ActionLink. Rather than passing `Model.Date` pass `Model.Date.ToString()`. You might need to modify a few other bits and pieces, I'm not sure. The basic idea is to make it into a string before the framework gets its hand on it which will guarantee it will come out as it went in.

Comment: Yup, this works. It seems more like a workaround, but it will do for now in my case. Thanks Chris.

Comment: It is indeed a workaround but given the hardcoding to use invariant culture a workaround is the best you can get with your requirements. The other option of course being rethinking how you pass the data in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I would hard-code the culture and uiculture to da-DK

```
<globalization uiCulture="da-DK" culture="da-DK" />
```