# Filter list by date and time MVC/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to filter a list according to give start and end date, sometimes it does give me proper rows according to the info I've entered, sometimes not. Below is my query does anybody see any problem in logic?

```
public List<MyTicket> FilteredTickets => Tickets.Where(x =>
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TicketType) || x.RequestTypeId == TicketType) &&
        (StartDate == null || x.DateLogged >= StartDate) && (EndDate == null || x.DateLogged <= EndDate)).ToList();
```

Comment: Does the StartDate and EndDate contain hours and minutes?  Yo9u may want to use StartDate.Date and EndDate.Date to remove the hours and minutes.

Comment: It's a dropdown list so it has to allow the user to leave it blank (null) so that wasn't the error, but apparently the problem is since it was invoking the get method, instead of post. It was getting confused with date and time format. I've found some of the answers about setting up the global settings and culture in order to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a dropdown list so it has to allow the user to leave it blank (null) so that wasn't an error, but apparently the problem is since it was invoking the get method, instead of the post, it was getting confused with date and time format. I've found some of the answers about setting up the global settings and culture in order to solve this problem. [MVC DateTime binding with incorrect date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528545/mvc-datetime-binding-with-incorrect-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix as follows:

```
public List<MyTicket> FilteredTickets =
        Tickets.Where(x =>
        (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TicketType) && x.RequestTypeId == TicketType) &&
        (StartDate != null && x.DateLogged >= StartDate) && 
        (EndDate != null && x.DateLogged <= EndDate)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently checking if your `StartDate` and `EndDate` values are null or greater instead of not null and greater :

```
public List<MyTicket> FilteredTickets => Tickets.Where(x =>
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TicketType) || x.RequestTypeId == TicketType) &&
    (StartDate != null && x.DateLogged >= StartDate) && 
    (EndDate != null && x.DateLogged <= EndDate))
    .ToList();
```

So as soon as your previous expression was being evaluated, it would see that one of these date fields was null and evaluate the entire section as `true`, thus displaying the result as opposed to filtering it out.