# saving datetime with format yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss cause validation error in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

i have a model like this :

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime DateUpdate { get; set; }
```

and have a view :

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateUpdate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Helpers.EditVal(Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateUpdate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") } }))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateUpdate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

but i can't save it because i get validation error for dateupdate field ! what is wrong here ? i want to save this format `{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}` not mm/dd/yy or something else and i don't want to get validation error

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528545/mvc-datetime-binding-with-incorrect-date-format

Comment: thanks for link i have to say this works in firefox but not working in chrome and opera

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it with a quick change in my model :

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)] ======> [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
```

and it works fine now

Comment: after this i could write a custom validation too as this link say [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/mvc-4-custom-validation-data-annotation-attribute/)