# MVC FromUri ComplexType DateTime format

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

In my apicontroller, I have a get method that takes in a complex type ModelA, which consist of multiple fields and one of them is a DateTime.

I am passing in date format as "dd/MM/yyyy" but it is picking up as "MM/dd/yyyy"

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MethodA([FromUri]ModelA model)
{
}

public class ModelA
{
    public DateTime? FromDate {get;set;}
}
```

How can I have it to pick up the correct format?

What have I tried:

- overriding ExecuteBindingAsync on HttpParameterBinding and adding parameterBindingRule in HttpConfig
- overriding BindModel on DefaultModel Binder and adding the binder to ModelBinders

both overridden methods did not get called when I call the api

Comment: It may be due to your current locale/culture settings in your PC. You must either change the setting in your machine or set the preferred locale/culture in code.

Comment: I've added     <globalization  culture="en-MY"  uiCulture="en-MY"/> into my web.config and have changed the date format in controlpanel/clock to d/M/yyyy but it is still giving me M/d/yyyy in mvc

Comment: How you are checking the date format? Do you see the value of 'FromDate' in debugger or showing that date somewhere in your pages?

Comment: Can you add this line in your MethodA and see what is the culture the current thread is set to. Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name

Comment: @Thangadurai I put a breakpoint right in the first line of MethodA, I passed in the date as 3/5/2017 but the datetime object is telling me the day is 5 and month is 3

Comment: Please check what is the culture the current thread is set to. Use this stmt Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name

Comment: @Thangadurai it's en-MY

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC DateTime binding with incorrect date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528545/mvc-datetime-binding-with-incorrect-date-format)