# Issue when sending DateTime value to controller

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core

I am sending `DateTime` values from form to a controller. The field in the model is a `DateTime?`. When sending the value using `MM/dd/yyyy` the binding works correct and the value is available in the controller.

When changing the dateformat to `dd/MM/yyyy` the model binding is not working and the value is `null` when received inside the controller.

Any tips would be really helpfull here.

Comment: Consider editing your question and adding the relevant code

Comment: An option could be send as a string and then Convert.ToDateTime in the format you expect it, there are issues with Locale, browser locale, system locale too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528545/mvc-datetime-binding-with-incorrect-date-format

Comment: @bradbury9 the question is general and does not apply to specific code. It applies to all code when trying to send a date to a mvc controller in format dd/MM/yyyy so please do not ask for code examples when it is not relevant.

Comment: @Rav tnxs for the reply, i have already thought of that and tried it so i know that will work but i raises some concerns for me when i have to deal with hacks like that instead of understanding why it happends only for that specific date format.

Comment: @akg tnxs for the link. I forgot to specify that im running asp net core. and the thread you are linking to references older versions, Some of them with hacks which i do not like. I will have to dig deeper into how the modelbinder works and write a custom date model binder to solve this.